# Function local haskell Reader monad

Tags: haskell, monads

I consider if two below expressions are equivalent:

```
env <- ask
local (\_ -> env) sth
```

and:

```
local (\env -> env) sth
```

If not, where it is taken to the argument lambda?

Comment: In the second fragment, Instead of `(_env -> env)` do you mean `(\env -> env)` ?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: The second snippet is very strange. Please rework it to be more meaningful or add comments. The first snippet equals just `sth`, since you don't change the environment with `local` (just return the already set env).

Comment: @ErikR, yes indeed

Comment: Both are the same as the computation `sth`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not really sure what your question is about, but let's try.

So you're asking if

```
ask >>= \env -> local (const env) sth
```

and

```
local id sth
```

are equivalent.

In terms of effect -- sure they are. What's more they're both equivalent to just `sth`. Let us consider an example that's a little bit more complicated:

```
ask >>= \env -> local (const (f env)) sth
```

vs

```
local f sth
```

Let us now try to understand how it works.

`local` is defined as

```
local :: (r -> r) -> Reader r a -> Reader r a
local f m = Reader $ runReader m . f
```

(I'm simplifying a bit, since it's actually defined for `ReaderT` via `withReaderT`, but it gets the idea across)

As a reminder, we can assume

```
runReader :: Reader r a -> r -> a
```

Also, as a reminder `Reader r a` is a newtype that wraps `r -> a`.

Now, what does `>>=` do here? Simple,

```
m >>= k  = Reader $ \r -> runReader (k (runReader m r)) r
```

So, it takes `m`, extracts value from it, and passes it to `k`, while keeping actual environment `r` as a free parameter. As a well-behaved monadic bind should, so no surprise here.

Also bears noting, that `ask` is just `Reader id`

Now then, let's drop whole `Reader` thing altogether and just rewrite our expressions as functions.

```
ask >>= \env -> local (const (f env)) sth
```

then becomes

```
\r -> (\r' -> runReader sth (const (f r) r')) r
```

and

```
local f sth
```

becomes

```
\r -> runReader sth (f r)
```

Now if you squint a bit, you could see that these two are equivalent in terms of effect. Indeed,

```
const (f r) r' = f r
(\r' -> runReader sth (f r)) r = (\_ -> runReader sth (f r)) r
                               = runReader sth (f r)
```

So

```
\r -> (\r' -> runReader sth (const (f r) r')) r
```

turns into

```
\r -> runReader sth (f r)
```

Which is exactly the same as `local f sth`.

Now the question is, is your compiler smart enough to do this transformation on its own? If I had to guess, I would guess GHC *is* indeed smart enough, since it's all basic algebraic equality. But luckily, I don't *have* to guess, because I can check.

Using these two sources, `test1.hs`:

```
import Control.Monad.Reader

main :: IO ()
main = print $ runReader m "hello"

f = (++"!!!")

m = ask >>= \r -> local (const (f r)) ask
```

and `test2.hs`:

```
import Control.Monad.Reader

main :: IO ()
main = print $ runReader m "hello"

f = (++"!!!")

m = local f ask
```

I ran `ghc -O2 -ddump-simpl` on both of them (using GHC 7.10.3). Guess what, core files differ only in randomized names.

Granted, without `-O2` output differs quite a bit. But that is expected.